# .NET IConfiguration returns null for a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

My breakpoints were out of sync so I had to change my launch.json's `program` property to point at the new folder that .NET2.0.0 creates.

Now when my app tries to get a property from the app.Development.json file it ends up being null:

`

```
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
                    {
                        // delete all default configuration providers
                        hostCtx = hostContext;
                        var hostConf = hostContext.Configuration;
                        var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;
                        config.Sources.Clear();
                        config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
                        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                              .AddEnvironmentVariables();
// these both are null                        
                        certFileName = hostConf["AppConfiguration:CertFileName"];
                        certPassword = hostConf["AppConfiguration:CertPassword"];
                    })
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if I do:

 `var c = config.Build();`

And use `c` instead of `hostConf` it works.

I'm not sure why though since I thought the hostContext would contain the Configuration already. If anyone knows why or a cleaner way, I'm all ears.